# Unable to access Grafana UI

Tags: linux, grafana, firewall

I installed Grafana in an AWS linux machine. Post that i started Grafana server also which is there in bin folder. But still i am unable to access Grafana UI from a web browser. I am using below URL to access Grafana UI

```
http://52.209.135.66:8000/
```

I tried to check connectivity from terminal by using below command

```
wget http://52.209.135.66:8000/
```

the output of the command is

```
--2020-07-22 17:40:12--  http://52.209.135.66:8000/
Connecting to 52.209.135.66:8000... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2020-07-22 17:42:22--  (try: 2)  http://52.209.135.66:8000/
Connecting to 52.209.135.66:8000...
```

As suggested in few online articles i executed below command to remove the firewall settings, still it is not accessible

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: aws , maybe it is just a security group issue ?  on aws side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following areas:

1. Inbound Rule for the Security Groups attached to your instance: they must allow for port 8000 coming from 0.0.0.0/0
2. Custom Network ACLs associated with the VPC subnet where your instance is provisioned (Default ACL should allow all traffic). Ensure either all traffic is allowed or there are rules that allow inbound traffic on port 8000 from 0.0.0.0/0 AND outbound traffic to anywhere on the peripheral ports.
3. The instance is in a public subnet: that is, there's route from the subnet to the Internet Gateway.
4. The IP address is associated with your instance

Comment: Thanks for the above comments peter, can you please let me know how to check these setting through terminal as i dont have access for AWS console?

Comment: What you need is likely a series of aws cli ec2 calls. Please see the documentation for that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html#cli-aws-ec2. You want to be ale to describe the instance and the security groups associated with your instance.